# I am having trouble running a java program that calculates the gcd of two numbers with a try /catch exception

Tags: java, try-catch

I try to calculate the gcd without an exception but the 1st time I executed the code, it said I needed an exception for numbers divided by zero. When I added the try/catch exception, it still wouldn't calculate by gcd. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class methodone {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int factor1;
        int factor2;
        int r;
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 1st factor");
        factor1=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd factor");
        factor2=input.nextInt();
        while(factor1!=0){
            try{  
                r = factor1 % factor2;
                factor1 = factor2;
                factor2 = r;
            }
            catch{
                System.out.println("can't divide by zero");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("GCD is"+factor1);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Your question is more likely to be answered if you format your code to be more readable and throw in some comments to explain your current thought process.

Answer (score 0):

```
        try{  
            r = factor1 % factor2;
            factor1 = factor2;
            factor2 = r;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("can't divide by zero");
        }
```

edit: This does what you want.

```
static int gcd(int a, int b)
{
  while(a!=0 && b!=0) // until either one of them is 0
  {
     int c = b;
     b = a%b;
     a = c;
  }
  return a+b; // either one is 0, so return the non-zero value
}
```

Comment: Now it just prints the message "can't divide by zero" infinitely many times, instead of printing the two common factors. Do I need to be the catch statement outside the wild loop?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer already that provides a correct algorithm for your problem. I think it is important to make another point here:
An Exception is there to handle exceptional situations. Division by zero is something you can easily anticipate and check, i.e. it is not an exception. That means for your code: don't catch the Exception but check parameters explicitly bofore you divide anything.

This will also avoid the very annoying and unnecessary situation that an Exception is thrown for another reason and you still alert the user that you "can't divide by zero".